# Best practices if your Build is taking too long in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, language-agnostic

I have moderate size solution in Visual Studio which takes around 5 minutes to build (It take that long because of FxCop and other post build steps).
My problem is, Visual Studio stops responding while it's building. You can't continue working as VS almost hangs. I tried using two VS instances, just using one for build, but it keeps crashing every now and then.

My question is, How to not waste time looking at Visual Studio building your large/moderate project. Are there any best practices for this?

Answer (score 38):

[image]

[Source](http://xkcd.com/303/).

Comment: ref: http://www.xkcd.com

Comment: How does this answer the question? Its just a sarcastic comic/meme

Comment: @Prateek it was added back when Stack Overflow had a sense of humor

Comment: I am sorry, I dint find it befitting to be answer worthy. I would be penalized if this answer came up on review section. :)

Answer (score 7):

Two excellent MSBuild tips I just learned yesterday...

You can run tasks in parallel by using the /m:n switch where n is the number of processors to use. All you have to do is set [BuildInParallel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb651793.aspx) on your MSBuild task.

The other trick is that if you have several <exec /> tasks to run you can actually run them in parallel too by calling <exec command="sleep 10|sleep 10|sleep 20" /> by using the pipe character between each command. A more practical example:

```
<CreateItem Include="server1;server2;server3;server2">
  <Output ItemName="IISServer" TaskParameter="Include"/>
</CreateItem>
<CreateProperty Value="@(IISServer->'iisreset.exe /start %(Identity)', '|')">
  <Output TaskParameter="Value" PropertyName="IISServerStartAll" />
</CreateProperty>
<exec command="$(IISServerStartAll)" />
```

Comment: That's interesting, sound like more speed for free.  But I know *absolutely* nothing about build.  If I am doing start and debug "builds" in VS where do I find this file or alter the setting in the UI?

Comment: This would be in MSBuild scripts that you write yourself. I'd definitely recommend taking FxCop out of every build, that is unnecessary. You can set up separate build processes in VS. I'd suggest one for just compiling what you are working on and one that runs all your code checking and tests.

Comment: +1 The You could use the [potentially in-target] PropertyGroup/ItemGroup syntax to make the example even clearer... Also Tools|Options Projects and Solutions|Build and Run|maximum number of parallel project builds controls it externally

Comment: Also buy the Hashimi MSBuild book

Answer (score 5):

1. You certainly don't need to run a
   static code analysis each time you
   build your solution.
2. Reduce the number of your project by
   merging some could also helps a lot.

What other post build tasks have you put in place ?

Comment: +1 A agree with that, you should consider running a build server with CruiseControl.NET which will run your static code analysis, unit tests, code coverage (Ncover), coding standards (StyleCop), class structure analysis (NDepends), etc... You can set up a build to do so just before you check in too.

Comment: TeamCity is really easy to set up...

Comment: We don't run any analysis when in DEBUG mode for this very reason.  Once the Developer believes that they're nearing the end of the development cycle then they put it in Release Mode which is when we run our Code Analysis etc.

Answer (score 1):

Use Incredibuild if you have more than one computer or setup this program to another friends at work. 
it is easy to setup and use. 
speed up is linear for compiling.

it is also good for multicore cpu's bacause normally vs uses one core for one project but incredibuild make it parallel for each .cpp file...

try and see.. :)

Answer (score 0):

You might consider a dedicated build machine using MSBuild. From there, you'd be able to continue working while compiling.  It does make it more complicated, though, as you're introducing networking issues.

Answer (score -1):

You can create classes in another project by stubbing the classes that you would need to make the code compiles. This way, you can test and document your new code. After this, you just include it to the real project and you compile "for real". By the time it compiles, you are already working on another snippet of the project because you are 95% it will successfully compiles. Or, by the time it compiles, you can also write your unit tests..

Comment: The problem is not "what to do while it compiles", but more "how to use Visual Studio while it compiles, given that starting two instances makes it crash".